# A Bit or a bit of

Tags: grammar

Which way is correct:
*learn a bit of a grammar* or *learn a bit grammar*?
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Merriam-webster    Dictionary  :

a bit of a/an

An idiom 
- used to make a statement or description less forceful or definite.
For example:
 I had a bit of a shock when I saw him.
So, 'a bit of a grammar' is correct.
'A bit' /meaning 'a little'/ as an adverb can be used with adjectives  and adverbs: a bit late, a bit early, a bit difficult, etc.